# Как оправлять заявки с сайта в Trello?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, trello

Вот мой код (делал по гайду) должно все работать но не работает( Помогите пожалуйста !

HTML ФОРМА

```
<form id="order_form" name="title" class="order_form" action="/sendmail.php" method="post">
                
    <select id="color" class="field _req" name="color" placeholder="Укажите цвет">
            <option disabled>Выберите цвет</option>
            <option value="Бордо">Бордо</option>
            <option value="Синий">Синий</option>
            <option value="Электрик">Электрик</option>
            <option value="Розовый">Розовый</option>
                   
    </select>
    <select id="size" class="field _req" name="size" placeholder="Укажите размер">
            <option disabled>Выберите размер</option>
            <option value="48-50">РАЗМЕР 48-50</option>
            <option value="52-54">РАЗМЕР 52-54</option>
            <option value="56-58">РАЗМЕР 56-58</option>
                    
                  
               
        </select>
                    
        <input type="text" name="title" value="" hidden="">
    <input class="field _req" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Введите Ваше имя" required="" value="">
    <input class="field _req" type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="Введите Ваш телефон" required="" value="">

    <button type="submit" class="button">Оставить заявку</button>
```

PHP Отправка в Trello

```
?>
    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/vendor/autoload.php');
  
    $api_key = '545435a153c325ab22943d326c612e91';
    $returned_token = '457c1b648fb941fe1778ab3495904232f3fa5ac8f4d94149ef3e0ccd1e3a0507';
    $client = new \Trello\Client($api_key);

    $client->setAccessToken($returned_token);

    $list_id = '5e56c64642fb612178ef9b0d';
    $card = new \Trello\Model\Card($client);
    $card->name = $_POST['name'] . ', оставил заявку';
    $card->desc = 'Тема письма: ' . $_POST['title'] . '

- Имя: ' . $_POST['name'] . '
- Телефон: ' . $_POST['phone'] . '
- E-mail:
- Источник: ' . urldecode($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) . '
- IP Address: ' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $card->pos = 'top';
    $card->idLabels = array('5e30233d18d7bf4eda3cada6', '5e30276cb9e2613e40dc6e68', '5e29c4f2af955c41f2ac190d');
    $card->idList = $list_id;
    $card->idMembers = array('5dad34eed46f741c8839e3af');
    $card->save();
<?php
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Переходит на HTTP ERROR 500, и заявки в Trello нет

Answer (score 0):

1. Поставьте точку перед / здесь action="./sendmail.php"
2. После: "PHP Отправка в Trello" Вы перепутали открывающий и закрывающий тег php: замените ?> на <php со знаком ? между < и php . Также в конце вместо "<php со знаком ? между < и php" напишите ?>
3. Здесь также поставьте точку перед /vendor/autoload.php и получите: require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . './vendor/autoload.php');
   Извените, я не знаю что такое Trello, ибо не настала для меня пора для осмысливания этого продукта, поэтому далее моя помощь отсутствует.